# Rails 5.1 mailer wrong number of arguments given 0 expected 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I'm working on a Rails 5.1.2 app in Ruby 2.4.1.  I'm creating a simple mailer to use as seen below in the class:

```
  class PagingMailer < ApplicationMailer
      include SendGrid
      default from: Rails.application.secrets.no_reply_email

      def message(paging_id, email)
        @paging = Paging.find(paging_id)
        mail to: email, subject: "#{@paging.user.username} has sent you a message"
      end
    end
```

The `message` method in the `PagingMailer` class takes an argument of a `paging_id` (integer) and gets passed the second argument for the email address (string). Originally I had this fired with a sidekiq worker and it wouldn't deliver giving a wrong number of arguments given 0 expected 2 exception.

So I fired up a rails console and tried to do a simple test, getting sidekiq out of the way just in case.

```
Loading development environment (Rails 5.1.2)
irb(main):001:0> PagingMailer.message(33, "john@domain.com").deliver
PagingMailer#message: processed outbound mail in 69.1ms
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2)
    from app/mailers/paging_mailer.rb:5:in `message'
    from app/mailers/paging_mailer.rb:7:in `message'
    from (irb):1
```

The stacktrace points to line 5 and 7 in the message method which the common theme here is the email argument.

As a test I tried removing the second argument and hardcoding "john@domain.com" to the mail to: part so the method would only take a single argument of `paging_id`.  When I fire that from the Rails console I get the following:

```
irb(main):003:0> PagingMailer.message(33).deliver
PagingMailer#message: processed outbound mail in 27.4ms
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
    from app/mailers/paging_mailer.rb:5:in `message'
    from app/mailers/paging_mailer.rb:7:in `message'
```

I'm literally passing an argument to the method and it's not seeing it, even though it's being passed as an object.

It should be noted I have a few other mailers inside my app which are configured similarly to take 2 arguments and they perform properly.  But this specific mailer I'm strugglebussing with.

Not sure if I'm missing something totally obvious, or if this might be some sort of Rails bug.

Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think your problem has something to do with SendGrid setup. Erase 'include SendGrid' and test if works.

Comment: @PapayaLabs no, that's not the problem.  My other mailer classes use the same include declarative and work just fine.  I removed it by your request and it yields the same exception.

Comment: So maybe is in #{@paging.user.username}. I dont know how is your Paging Model. I do not see any otrher problem.

Comment: Try to remove all @paging object and see if works

Comment: @PapayaLabs it's not that either, as that instance variable is legitimate and its looked up via AR after the argument is passed.  The exception that is raised is not even relevant to the AR lookup.  It's the ActionMailer class the action method is not accepting arguments when they are being passed.  Please see the original question.

Comment: Removing the `@paging` object doesn't work and even if it did work I wouldn't be able to pass the object to my view for rendering which would make my mailer useless.

Comment: Ok I reproduce your code and if you change your method name 'message' works. That was the last variable to test. I really do not know why.

Comment: I think is a reserved word in ActionMailer

Comment: @PapayaLabs you were right, I was looking this up too in between comments.  I renamed the method to `new_message` and it worked! Thanks for the help, i'll accept your answer!

Comment: Your welcome! I am searching why is this happen.

Comment: @PapayaLabs it's part of the internals for ActionMailer, it's not a bug so no PR for either of us as it's a cosmetic change and rails core doesn't accept cosmetics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the name of method 'message'. ActionMailer::Base defines an attr_internal named 'message' so read and write instance methods are created and you are overriding it.